# How to Display Created By Field in InfoPath

Tags: list, infopath, forms-services

I am using InfoPath to create a custom form on the SP2010 list.  When the "created by" field is dropped on the design surface it uses a picker control.  How do you go about using a Textbox control to display the user name.  I don't see an options for this.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would add a calculated value to accomplish this.

Do not add your Created By field to the form template.

1. Add a Calculated Value from the Controls.
2. Go into the control
3. Select Insert field or Group
4. You wont see Created By at first, select show advanced view
5. Expand dataFields
6. Expand Created By
7. Expand pc:Person
8. Select DisplayName
9. Click Ok

That should do it (just tested). Note that it wont show on new forms for obvious reasons.

Comment: awesome Cory!  did not think of that !